# To remove an element and assign the list in one line

Tags: python, list

So as the question says, is it possible to remove an element and return the list in one line?

So if lets say

```
a = [1, 3, 2, 4]
b = a.remove(1)
```

This would set b to be NoneType, so I was wondering if there's a way to do this.

Comment: It is the standard behavior for in-place operations like `list.remove()` to return `None`. Doing otherwise would be non-standard behavior. Are you really absolutely 100% sure that you need to do this?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 yup I don't expect to use remove, just something else that can replicate it. I want to do this because I want to be able to use remove in a lambda.

Comment: What's stopping you from using `remove()` in a `lambda`?

Comment: do you plan to reuse `a` after assigning to `b`?

Comment: What are you *really* trying to do here?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Because removing something from a list is only a part of the lambda, its not the result of the lambda

Comment: You probably shouldn't be using a `lambda`, then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose this would work:

```
a = [1, 3, 2, 4]
b = (a.remove(1), a)[1]
```

This is assuming that you want to do both things:

1. Modify the original list by removing the element, and
2. Return the (now modified) list.

**EDIT**

Another alternative:

```
b = a.remove(1) or a
```

Both are fairly confusing; I'm not sure I would use either in code.

**EDIT 2**

Since you mentioned wanting to use this in a lambda... are you aware that you can use an actual named function any time you would otherwise use a lambda?

E.g. instead of something like this:

```
map(lambda x: x.remove(1) and x, foo)
```

You can do this:

```
def remove_and_return(x):
    x.remove(1)
    return x

map(remove_and_return, foo)
```

Comment: Don't worry this isn't going to be used in production code, just trying to write a solution in 1 line.

Comment: Ah, if the goal is "code golf," then I think the `or` variant is likely to be the shortest.

Answer (score 2):

Since `remove` returns `None`, you could just `or a` to it:

```
>>> a = [1, 3, 2, 4]
>>> a.remove(1) or a
[3, 2, 4]
```

Comment: The other person answered first so I accepted his answer but ty

Answer (score 0):

List `a` assign to `b`:

```
b = a.remove(1) or a  
a is b     # True
```

Using `b` is the same to use `a`, and it's dangerous if you get a final object like `[b, c, d]`,  because if you update one of this list element, the all elements will *update* too.

Compare to:

```
import copy
b = a.remove(1) or copy.copy(a)
```

I think this way should be safer.

Answer (score 0):

pure functional solution that does not touch passed list

```
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> (lambda a,b: (lambda a0,a1: (a0.remove(b),a1)[-1] )( *((a.copy(),)*2) ))(a, 3)
[1,2]
>>> a
[1,2,3]
```