# Removing an item and printing the list in one line

Tags: python, list

I was looking for a one-line way to remove an item from a list and then print the list.  The first bit of code works and is straight forward and does what I want:

```
alist = ["a", "b", "c"]
alist.remove("b")
print(alist)
```

Which produces the result we want: `["a", "c"]`

But when I tried to make it one line:

`print(["a","b","c"].remove("b"))`

It returns `None`.  Can someone explain the difference between these? I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38580337/to-remove-an-element-and-assign-the-list-in-one-line) but it does not explain why these produce different outputs, and does not really make it all work in one line.

And this is not actually important for anything, I am just trying to learn what is going on here.  Thanks.

Comment: [`remove`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) modifies the list in-place, it returns `None`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [remove() returns None when I try to remove a variable from a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45046415/remove-returns-none-when-i-try-to-remove-a-variable-from-a-list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `remove` acts on the list object upon which it was called. So after `alist.remove("b")`, the name `alist` refers to a list `["a", "c"]`.
However, the method `remove` does not *return* the list `a`. There is no need for the method to return anything (because it does its job *in-place*, that is on the list `alist`). Thus the return value is `None`. (Also see [the documentation](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/list/remove.html).)

If you do

```py
print(["a", "b", "c"].remove("b"))
```

then the return value is printed, i.e. `None`. If you do

```py
alist = ["a", "b", "c"]
alist.remove("b")
print(alist)
```

then `alist` is printed (after it has been modified by `remove()`. The latter is usually what you want.

Concerning your desire to have this as a one-liner: I would not recommend you to remove a list element and print the resulting list in one line. It usually makes your code quite hard to read. Instead, the code you provided is just fine (it's a two-liner if you don't count the initialization of `alist`).
But if you are still curious to do this in one line, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38580371/16751401). You mentioned the same thread in your question; I think the answer is fine in giving a one line solution.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the `remove` function works [in place](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/inplace-operator-in-python). An in-place function doesn't have a return value (which is why you get `None`) and in `print(["a","b","c"].remove("b"))` you are effectively trying to send the return value of the in place `remove` function to the `print` function.

As you correctly stated,

```
alist = ["a", "b", "c"]
alist.remove("b")
print(alist)
```

would be the correct use of a in-place function.

Answer (score -1):

> Remove method won't return any value in python it just remove a
> element from the list.

```
    print(["a","b","c"].remove("b"))
```

In the above case remove() just remove "b" value and returns Nothing Thats why it shows "None" as output

You can check it with below code

```
l=["d","e","f"]
print(l.remove("e"))
print(l)
```